# Schwinger's computation of anomalous magnetic moment of electron

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, perturbation-theory, magnetic-moment

I am trying to understand the details of the computation of the anomalous magnetic moment of electron (due to Schwinger). As far as I understand it reduces to study of an element of the $S$-matrix in QED in presense of exterior magnetic field. The computation uses perturbation theory staring with a Lagrangian depending on the exterior field.

> How does this Lagrangian look like exactly in terms of physical constants and fields? In particular, are there counter-terms depending on the exterior field?

Answer (score 2):

The additional term to the QED Lagrangian is simply $J_\mu A^\mu$ with $J_\mu$ an external current. There is no counter-term associated with this term. The external current couples with the renormalized field $A^\mu$.

Intuitively, the external current produces a field that can interact with electrons. The interaction contains the combined effects of the electron's charge and magnetic moment due to its spin. To compute the anomalous magnetic moment, we then need to single out the contribution connected to the electron's spin.

Effectively, the calculation to the first non-trivial order involves a single Feynman graph. No need to worry about any counter-terms since they don't contribute to the spin-related part of the interaction.

(Schwinger of course did it without drawing any Feynman diagrams but that is the gist of it.)

**Edit:** The relevant Feynman diagram (taken from Lectures of Sidney Coleman)
[image]

The 'dot' represents the classical source $\tilde{J}_\mu (k)$.

Comment: What actually bothers me is that formula (14.1.1) in Weinberg's book "The quantum theory of fields" shows that there is a counter term depending on the exterior field. It is claimed that that was shown in Section 13.6. I do not see how this term arises there; there is no mention of it in Section 13.6. May be there are some omitted details.

Comment: BTW do I understand correctly your notation: is it true that $J_\mu=e\bar \psi\gamma_\mu\psi$? In that case $e,\psi$ are  bare of physical charge and field respectively?

Comment: @MKO No, $e\bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu\psi$ is the current produced by the electron field, not the external current $J_\mu$ I referred to. Weinberg's Eq. 14.1.1 has the Dirac field coupled directly with an external vector potential. Whereas above, we have a current coupled with the "photon" field, not the same thing.

Comment: I am confused. It seems that your lagrangian does not depend on the exterior EM field at all. This seems to me strange since magnetic moment is a reaction of electron to exterior stationary magnetic field. This is also different from all the textbooks on the subject I have seen so far.

Comment: @MKO The Lagrangian has an additional term $J_\mu A^\mu$. The external current $J_\mu$ "emits" photons that then interact with the electron via the QED vertex.

Comment: I think in literature the situation is different. One adds to Lagrangian $-ie\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\psi\mathcal{A}^\mu$ where $\mathcal{A}^\mu$ is a classical EM potential. Possibly one should add something else, and this is what my question is about.

Comment: @MKO Look at Weinberg's Figure 11.4d. That is the relevant Feynman diagram. Notice there we have an external photon line. If both the incoming and outgoing electrons are on-shell, because of 4-momentum conservation, the photon cannot be on-shell and has to be virtual. So we need a source to produce that virtual photon. That is why we need to introduce the source $J_\mu$.

Comment: @MKO Adding $-ie\bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu\psi \mathcal{A}^\mu$ gives the same effect. $\mathcal{A}^\mu$ represents the off-shell photon. For the calculation of the anomalous magnetic moment, no counterterm is needed. And you can see why adding $J_\mu A^\mu$ is easier and gives a clearer picture.

Comment: $-e\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\psi\mathcal{A}^\mu$ is used in all the literature I know. I do not see how to relate $J_\mu A^\mu$ to magnetic moment when $J_\mu$ is external current. Do you have a reference? Regarding extra counter terms, see my reference to the Weinberg's book above.

Comment: @MKO To compute the anomalous magnetic moment, all you need is the Feynman diagram in Weinberg's figure 11.4d. The issue, like I said, is that the photon coming into the vertex has to be off-shell. To justify that, one can imagine having a classical source and that photon would be coming from the source to the vertex, i.e. it is an internal virtual photon. If you have access to "Lectures of Sidney Coleman on QFT", the calculation is done in lecture 34.

Comment: @MKO see the diagram I added on the post above

Comment: Does one attach the photon propagator to the external photon line in that diagram?

Comment: @MKO Yes. The photon coming from the 'dot' is internal, you treat it as with any other internal photon line.